# CI global variables

Tags: php, codeigniter, global-variables

I want a global variable that can be changed by any controller.
in `class CI_Controller` is set.

```
    var $global
```

in the `__construct()`

```
    $this->global = array(
            'account' => '1234567',
            'name' => 'George',
            'dob' => '08/20/1960'
        );
```

OK, this all works from any controller extending `CI`.
If i change the the global in one controller it is not reflected in another controller. IE `$global['name'] = 'Harry';` Will keep Harry global for that controller but will revert back to George when I go into another controller.

I kind of expected the ability to change the global in any controller.
What am I missing here.
Thanks in advance.

-ralph

Answer (score 1):

If you need dynamic data, use **sessions** or **cookies**. It's much flexible than you will play around with static data in php code. But if you want to use only global variable, create some [CodeIgniter Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) that will change variables data and call it in __construct() method. Also read about [CodeIgniter Hooks](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html?highlight=hook), maybe it will be useful too.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a core controller call it `MY_Controller` inside `application/core` and pretty much make any other controller extends my_controller then you got access to every variable inside this class:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public $global;
}
```

Then in any other controller:

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->global = 'something';
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working. I would like to show you the code but the editor is limiting me to 500 chars. How do I post my code?

Comment: @RalphPorter just edit your original question and add your code.